# C# ascii game collision

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ascii, collision

I need help with my ascii games collision. I already know how to make it when the player hits another object it does something. But I'm kinda confused when I want the player to stop when the player hits the object.

I use this when the player collides with another object.

```
if(player.x == object.x && player.y == object.y)
  {
       //Does something
  }
```

So if you could help me that would be awesome because I'v been at the collision thing for a while and I want to implement it into my game so it could possibly be a maze like game. Thank you for reading :3

here is the structure of my game "WHOLE CODE":

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 40;
        int y = 12;
        int ax = 23;
        int ay = 7;
        int apple = 0;
        int starX = 64;
        int starY = 5;
        int score = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int time = 100;
        int xt;
        int yt;
        bool quit = false;
        Console.Title = "Catch and Run";

        while (quit == false)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

            //Blocks
            Console.SetCursorPosition(29, 18);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;

            //Clear Screen
            Console.Clear();

            //Players
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.Write("☻");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(ax, ay);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("o");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(starX, starY);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.Write("☻");
            Console.ResetColor();

            //score
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("People: " + score);
            //apples
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Apples: " + apple);
            //Total
            Console.SetCursorPosition(40, 0);
            total = apple + score;
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + total);
            //Timer
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 23);
            Console.WriteLine("Steps Left: "+time);
            time--;

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(false);

            //key controlls
            switch (keyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (y > 1)
                        y--;

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    if (y < 22)
                        y++;

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (x > 0)
                        x--;

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if (x < 79)
                        x++;

                    break;
            }
            // Randomize Blacks
            if (x == starX && y == starY)
            {

                Random random = new Random();
                starX = random.Next(0, 80);
                starY = random.Next(1, 22);
                score += 10;
                time += 30;
            }
            //Randomize Apples
            if (x == ax && y == ay)
            {

                Random random = new Random();
                ax = random.Next(0, 80);
                ay = random.Next(1, 22);
                apple += 5;
                time += 20;
            }
            // Game Over timer set to 0
            if (time == 0)
            {

                Console.Clear();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(40, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER");

                Console.WriteLine("Score" + total);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
                quit = true;
            }
            if (x == 29 && y == 18)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = 1;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you move the player? your player should just be moving at a velocity and then you can just set that to 0

Answer (score 4):

This feels like you're new to C#/object oriented programming. My answer will be a little involved but I welcome further questions.

Answering your core question, "I want the player to stop when the player hits the object," you'll need to find out where the human player wants to move the hero, then do a collision detection, and if the player is not blocked, you then move him.

If this is eventually going to be a maze-like game, you'll need to store the playing field somehow. A simple way to go about this is:

```
char[,] maze = new char[25,80]; // [y,x]
```

You should start by creating this array, placing a few apples into it, and then show the board.

For example, we can place an apple at 5,5 by doing:

```
maze[5,5] = 'o';
```

Once showing the board works, you can then extend it to create walls, such as:

```
for(int by=10; by<20; by++)
{
   maze[by, 0] = '#';
   maze[by, 2] = '#';
}
```

That will create a 10-high corridor at the left of the screen.

Printing the board should happen after your call to Clear:

```
for (int by = 0; by < 25; by++)
{
    for (int bx = 0; bx < 80; bx++)
    {
        Console.Write(maze[by, bx]);
    }
}
```

To satisfy your collision detection, you'll want to do something like this:

```
// !! Replace your switch with this, then continue experimenting

int tempX, tempY;

tempX = x;
tempY = y;

switch (keyInfo.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
        quit = true;
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
        if (tempY > 1)
            tempY--;
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        if (tempY < 22)
            tempY++;
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
        if (tempX > 0)
            tempX--;
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
        if (tempX < 79)
            tempX++;
        break;
}

// Bounds checking already done by switch

if(maze[tempY, tempX] == '#')
{
    // Collision with wall is detected - forbid player from moving
}
else if(maze[tempY, tempX] == 'o')
{
    // Collision with apple is detected, handle consuming an apple
    x = tempX; // Now we update the player's position
    y = tempY;
} else {
    x = tempX; // No collision with anything, simply update player's position
    y = tempY;
}
```

That's the brief revision you can do to your code. I strongly suggest you think about moving the various pieces of code into their own methods and even classes, in order to make your code easier to develop and maintain. You should aim for each method to have one responsibility (your main method here is doing way too much, a single-responsibility method is easier to code and easier to fix) and each class to have one responsibility.

For example, a method such as "bool CanMoveTo(int x, int y)" would allow you to place bounds checking and collision detection somewhere outside your Main, and then you can call this method to see if the player is making a valid move.

For classes, you might have a Board class that is in charge of managing the maze and the pieces on it, a BoardPiece class that represents different elements you can place in the maze, and the main program would be responsible for displaying the board to the player.

Good luck with your game!